# Clear cell value of adjacent cell if value is a date

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on this script in Google Apps Script for a little while now and think I've got it almost figured out.  I could really use another pair of eyes though, as it hasn't yet worked to completion.

What I'm trying to do:

I'm working on a sheet dealing with tentative and actual dates.  These two dates are in adjacent columns.  Once the "actual" date gets filled into its cell, I would like the "tentative" date to be deleted.

Here is my script thus far:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange('F4:F');
  var range2 = sheet.getRange('E4:E');
  var rule = range.getDataValidation();
  if (rule != null) {
    var criteria = rule.getCriteriaType();
    var args = rule.getCriteriaValues();
    var clear = range2.clear({validationsOnly: false});
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to get this script running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you want to delete the value in column E if column F was filled. If so, I don't see the need for dealing with data validation rules. The following script checks that the edited cell is in column F, row >= 4, and that the new value in the cell is a date.  If these conditions hold, it clears the cell to the left (using `offset`).

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getColumn() == 6 && e.range.getRow() >= 4) {
    if (e.range.getValue() instanceof Date) {
      e.range.offset(0, -1).clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Note: this script uses the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) passed to onEdit function. Interestingly, its "value" property turned out  to be not useful here, because it is not a date object even when a user enters a date. This is what I use `e.range.getValue()` instead.